# How to do login in Slim API

Tags: php, sql, slim

I'm trying to make a function that check if the given username/password is correct in my Slim() API.

I have a authenticate function that I call with:

```
$app->post('/authenticate', 'authenticate');
```

I'm trying to first get the password of the user, then use password_verify() to check if the password is correct, than generate a session key that will be put inside the database and finally return that it worked.

For some reason, I really can't figure this out.

Here is what I got so far:

```
function authenticate($req, $resp, $args) {
    $credentials = json_decode($req->getBody());
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ict_users WHERE usr_username = ....";
    try {
        $db = DB_Connection();
        ......... 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

I'm not even sure if I actually got credentials, even do I know I sent them like this:

```
function Login(credentials) {
        $http.post(appConfig.apiURL + '/authenticate', credentials)
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log("succes!");
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status){
            console.log("error!");
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to first get the password of the user

What you want is `$request->getParsedBody()`

> I'm not even sure if I actually got credentials, even do I know I sent them like this:

But be careful regarding the content-type of the request you are sending. Check that if it doesn't work automatically

Comment: I don't understand the warning you're giving me: "But be careful regarding the content-type of the request you are sending. Check that if it doesn't work automatically"

Comment: I found it, it was $credentials = json_decode($req->getBody()); I just wasnt using it wright